# Parse a ziped XML file with PHP from an URL

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, unzip

I would like to parse a XML file from URL and with PHP. For the moment, with this code, I can have the content of the XML file, but I am not succeeding in using the **simplexml_load_string** in order to use it as a XML content.

Indeed, when I echo **zip**, the text appears without the XML tags. Would you have an idea? Thanks.

```
<?php
$file = 'http://url_here_.zip';
$newfile = 'tmp_name_file.zip';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
echo "failed to copy $file...\n";}

 $zip = new ZipArchive();

 if ($zip->open($newfile)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
   } else {
    $zip->getFromName('Scrutins_XIV.xml');
    $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($zip));
    $zip->close();
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: If your `echo` is in a web page, you may find they are simply being treated as markup tags, have you tried looking at the source of the page display, or use PHP on the command line to show the full output.

Comment: Also, `getFromName` will give you the contents of the file, so you don't need to use `file_get_contents`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, the `echo` is in a web page, I understand now why tags do not appear. Still, even if I remove the `file_get_contents`, the `simplexml_load_string` does not work (the error is **simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$xml_string = $zip->getFromName('Scrutins_XIV.xml');
if ( $xml_string!= false ) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
}
```